# Regex for plain and accentuated chars, with spaces and dashes only inside the string

Tags: regex, jsonschema, regex-group

I'm trying to come up with a regex to use inside a JSON schema.
The constraints:

- from 0 to 100 chars string
- accepts letters, accentuated letters (no greek chars, but also include œ)
- accepts space, ' and - ONLY inside the string

I have a brute force approach:

```
"^((?![Ð×Þß÷þø])[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿŒœ]{1})((?![Ð×Þß÷þø])[-'a-zA-ZÀ-ÿŒœ ]{0,98})((?![Ð×Þß÷þø])[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿŒœ]{1})$"
```

This works.. almost: the character selection matches what I want. But it won't accept strings below 2 chars.
So, instead of creating three groups, is there a way to reject space, - and ' at the beginning and end of a group?

Bonus question: writing this I realize that contiguous spaces or dashes are not desirable either...

Comment: @wp78de: Thanks for the answer. It works for the first char, but not for the trailing one (if the string ends with a space, the space gets absorbed in the main group?)

Comment: The very specific and arcane list of characters looks like you are only targeting Latin-1 or something; but JSON is Unicode by definition.

Comment: For the record, `{1}` is never necessary or useful.

Comment: @triplee: Thanks for the remark. Do you mean I should identify my target characters differently? As for the {1}, I was using it to force the last group to look at a single character. But I guess the look-behind approach takes care of that.

Comment: `[a-z]` already identifies exactly one character; if the `{1}` was useful then surely `[a-z]{1}(1}` would be even better?

Comment: If you are targeting Latin-1 then you should mention that, yes. A proper solution would exclude strings in Chinese, Korean, Hebrew, Cyrillic, Devanagari etc and not just (a subset of) Greek. There are many accented Western characters which are not part of Latin-1, like Ÿ to pick one obvious example. How exactly should those be handled?

Comment: @wp78de: just did (different time zone here), thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with negative look-arounds, i.e. a look-ahead in front of it and a look-behind after it. And we also exclude the unwanted character group everywhere:

```
^((?!.*[Ð×Þß÷þø])(?![ '-])[-'a-zA-ZÀ-ÿŒœ ]{0,100})(?<![ '-])$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MlOvWg/2/)

Comment: Great, works better with the look-behind syntax.
However things are not working fully yet: the ß and other characters are rejected only on the first group's character, for instance aßßa is accepted.
Using `^(?![ '-])(((?![Ð×Þß÷þø])[-'a-zA-ZÀ-ÿŒœ ]){0,100})(?<![ '-])$` seems to work, but I don't understand why I end up with two capture groups...

Comment: This groups `[Ð×Þß÷þø]` should be disallowed entirely? Like this https://regex101.com/r/MlOvWg/2

Comment: Right, I intended to disallow these anywhere.

Comment: Perfect, your regex `^((?!.*[Ð×Þß÷þø])(?![ '-])[-'a-zA-ZÀ-ÿŒœ ]{0,100})(?<![ '-])$` does take care of things. Thank you!

Comment: @Will59 Great. Updated.